# Correct way to use beacon and region

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, altbeacon

Using iBeacon.
From what I understand, I should start scanning the beacons using "beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion" or "startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion".
But I try to create a region and when entering and exiting this they present the identifiers like "null", "null", "null"

I need to know when a particular beacon was no longer detected

Follow the code below, considering that in "LocusData.locusBeacons" is the ArrayList with the beacons previously registered

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Beacon aux = beacons.iterator().next();
                Log.i("ScanBeacon", "The beacon "+
                        aux.getId1().toString()+"|"+
                        aux.getId2().toString()+"|"+
                        aux.getId3().toString());

                LocusData.updateDistance(
                        aux.getId1().toString(),
                        aux.getId2().toString(),
                        aux.getId3().toString(),
                        aux.getDistance());
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notifyListView();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i("SCANNING", "ENTER: " +
                    region.getId1() + "|" +
                    region.getId2() + "|" +
                    region.getId3());
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i("SCANNING", "EXIT: " +
                    region.getId1() + "|" +
                    region.getId2() + "|" +
                    region.getId3());
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }
    });

    try {
        for (LocusBeacon i : LocusData.locusBeacons) {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(i.getId(),
                    Identifier.parse(i.getUUID()),
                    Identifier.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(i.getMajor())),
                    Identifier.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(i.getMinor()))));
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you monitor a region defined with all three parts of the identifier populated, then start monitoring, you will get a callback when that exact beacon stops being detected by doing this:

```
for (LocusBeacon i : LocusData.locusBeacons) {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region(i.getId(),
                Identifier.parse(i.getUUID()),
                Identifier.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(i.getMajor())),
                Identifier.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(i.getMinor()))));
}
```

The callback to `didExitRegion(Region region)` will have a region object with the same identifiers used to start monitoring for the specific beacon that disappeared.

For this to work, the string returned by `i.getId()` must be unique.

If you also are monitoring a region with all the identifiers set to null, then didExitRegion will fire for that region when all beacons disappear from view.